# ionic run android: Build failed with an exception

Tags: ionic-framework, android-sdk-tools

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':CordovaLib:processDebugResources'.

  > com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/home/vishal/sw/android/build-tools/23.0.3/aapt'' finished with non-zero exit value 127
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 3 mins 14.449 secs
Error: Error code 1 for command: /var/www/html/street_delight/svn/trunk/add_merchant_app/platforms/android/gradlew with args: cdvBuildDebug,-b,/var/www/html/street_delight/svn/trunk/add_merchant_app/platforms/android/build.gradle,-Dorg.gradle.daemon=true,-Pandroid.useDeprecatedNdk=true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android SDK works on 32-bit env, if you are using 64-bit env then add following:

```
sudo apt-get install lib32stdc++6
sudo apt-get install lib32z1
```

Thanks to [codelatte](https://codelatte.wordpress.com/2015/01/27/installing-the-android-sdk-on-ubuntu-14-04/)

Comment: I used fedora 24 and try to install sudo dnf install lib32stdc++6. but it says that package not found.

Comment: Please try:

sudo yum install libstdc++.i686 && 
sudo yum install ncurses-libs.i686 && 
sudo yum install zlib.i686

Comment: For me too same problem: I tried to build android but got same error. 

`FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':_debugCompile'.
   > Could not find any version that matches com.android.support:support-v13:23+.
`

Comment: @AshishBhosle I am using Windows and Ionic Angular Project. How do I install above 2 packages to my project?