# Ionic2 Build failed with an Exception

Tags: android, git, bash, angular, ionic2

I'm developing an Ionic2 application. Now I want to make a build but I'm getting  an error.I ran the 'ionic build android' command in Git Bash and the following error occurred.I tried with 'cordova build android' also, getting same error.Can anyone please guide me to overcome this error?

```
FAILED


 FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':CordovaLib:processDebugResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt


* Try:

Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.


BUILD FAILED

Total time: 2.421 secs

Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37861905/execution-failed-for-task-processdebugresources-cordova-ionic

Comment: Thank u suraj for your response. As said in the example there is no special characters in my application to change.