# ionic error: Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3

I try build application android with this command:

> ionic cordova run android

but I have this error:

> Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.

this is output ionic info:

> li packages: (C:\Users\med\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules)

```
@ionic/cli-utils  : 1.19.1
ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.19.1
```

global packages:

```
cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.0.0
```

local packages:

```
@ionic/app-scripts : 3.1.8
Cordova Platforms  : android 7.0.0 ios 4.5.4
Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2
```

System:

```
Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1
Node              : v6.11.1
npm               : 3.10.10
OS                : Windows 7
```

Environment Variables:

```
ANDROID_HOME : C:\Users\med\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
```

Misc:

```
backend : pro
```

how to resolve this error please

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Execution failed for task :processDebugResources \[ Cordova / Ionic \]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37861905/execution-failed-for-task-processdebugresources-cordova-ionic)

Comment: @MichaWiedenmann I found this questions but also error :(

Answer (score 1):

this type of error occurs when a plugin might not be insatlled properly.. or the plugin is not behaving properly due to any reason.. If you recently added any native plugin try removing it and then try to build the app again if the build completes then you know what is causing the problem..

Comment: but all plugin has installed with succeful :(

Comment: in my experience some plugins were conflicting with each other.. trying running, `npm i` one time. And can you share the output of `ionic cordova plugin ls`.

Comment: error exact is : Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> Failed to execute aapt

Answer (score 0):

I have just fixed this issue by going to the platform/android folder and edited the `project.properties`) file and replaced `**com.android.support:support-v4:+**` with `**com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.0**`.